# Jquery plugin of WYSIWYG editor for adding Youtube / Vomio video links

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, editor, wysiwyg

Is there any Jquery plugin of WYSIWYG editor for adding Youtube / Vomio video links.

I have checked many Jquery plugins of WYSIWYG editor. But none of them giving me facility for adding video links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add youtube videos from following plugins:
1)Tiny MCE
2)CKEditor

And also we can add customize youtube button from extensions:
Use any of following links:

> [Link1](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Youtube_videos_repository)
>
> [Link2](http://leekelleher.com/2009/07/16/add-youtube-plugin-to-umbraco-tinymce/)